# How to get React Native Push Notifications using FCM?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-push-notification

I'm using React Native Push notifications for my iOS version of my React Native app and I'm trying to send a test notification using Firebase Cloud Messaging.

Here's my code that I have in a PushController.js file that I import into my app.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PushNotificationIOS from "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios";
import PushNotification from "react-native-push-notification";
// var PushNotification = require("react-native-push-notification");
export default class PushController extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    PushNotification.configure({
      // (optional) Called when Token is generated (iOS and Android)
      onRegister: function (token) {
        console.log("TOKEN:", token);
      },

      // (required) Called when a remote is received or opened, or local notification is opened
      onNotification: function (notification) {
        console.log("NOTIFICATION:", notification);
        // process the notification
        // (required) Called when a remote is received or opened, or local notification is opened
        notification.finish(PushNotificationIOS.FetchResult.NoData);
      },

      // (optional) Called when Registered Action is pressed and invokeApp is false, if true onNotification will be called (Android)
      onAction: function (notification) {
        console.log("ACTION:", notification.action);
        console.log("NOTIFICATION:", notification);
        // process the action
      },

      // (optional) Called when the user fails to register for remote notifications. Typically occurs when APNS is having issues, or the device is a simulator. (iOS)
      onRegistrationError: function (err) {
        console.error(err.message, err);
      },

      // IOS ONLY (optional): default: all - Permissions to register.
      permissions: {
        alert: true,
        badge: true,
        sound: true,
      },

      // Should the initial notification be popped automatically
      // default: true
      popInitialNotification: true,

      /**
       * (optional) default: true
       * - Specified if permissions (ios) and token (android and ios) will requested or not,
       * - if not, you must call PushNotificationsHandler.requestPermissions() later
       * - if you are not using remote notification or do not have Firebase installed, use this:
       *     requestPermissions: Platform.OS === 'ios'
       */

      requestPermissions: true,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return null;
  }
}
```

It properly initializes and I get the token from onRegister().

[image]

But, I can't get the FCM to output a notification to my app; I've added the token to my test but I don't believe it works because it is an FCM token. So my question is how do I send a message using FCM and connect it to the React Native Push Notifications?
[image]